# VPN connection - any mean against server being hacked?

Tags: security, vpn, webserver

as per my understanding the answer to this would be mainly **no**.

As it's only making the traffic between such a server and whoever is accessing it through that VPN better then only an encrypted SSL connection (not even sure if that is the case).

In my usecase it's an ERP application on that server, accessed by users via a browser interface from the outside world.

The only benefit in regards to hardening a (Linux) server would be that passwords being transferred are less likely to be picked up on their way.

Is that understanding accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a VPN only protects the communication channel between the VPN endpoints. And a well secured VPN should be sufficiently resistant to attack that you can effectively discount that risk.

It does nothing to harden either end - which is why attackers either try to compromise an endpoint, or try to make you connect to a spoof endpoint that they control.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean exactly by _"a weak secured VPN should be sufficiently resistant to attack that you can discount it."_

Comment: I blame autocucumber...